# what is the data byte encoded in binary Hamming code?

Tags: computer-science

the problem I am presented with is a binary hamming code shown below:

> 011101000100, what was the data byte encoded and sent from this hamming code?

and the solution is `10101100`, could someone explain to me how to approach this problem?

Comment: Also posted on CS.SE: http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/50879/755

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to calculate the parity bits of data, as follows:
$\dot0\dot11\dot1010\dot00100$

```
p1(0)(10000) 1 error because number of 1s is odd
p2(1)(11010) 
p4(0)(0100)
p8(0)(0100) 1 error
1 + 8 = 9, this is the bit where you have the error
```

now we replace the `0` in the **9th** bit with `1`, and after you take out the parity bits, you are then left with $10101100$